Characterization of alternative minimimum in convex programming
In Hans Paul Künzi, Wilhelm Krelle: Nichtlineare Programmierung on page 55 we can find the following statement:

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable and convex function on $X$. If $x^\ast$ is a minimum $f$ on $X$, then $f$ attains the minimum also at $\hat{x}\in X$ if and only if
\begin{equation*}
  \mathrm{grad} f(x^\ast)=\mathrm{grad} f(\hat{x})
 \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 \left<\mathrm{grad} f(x^\ast),\hat{x}-x^\ast\right>=0
\end{equation*}

The proof of $\Longrightarrow$ is quite simple; since f is convex, we have
\begin{equation*}
 f(x^\ast)-f(\hat{x})\geq \left<\mathrm{grad} f(\hat{x}),x^\ast-\hat{x}\right>=0,
\end{equation*}
i.e., $f(x^\ast)\geq f(\hat{x})$, and thus $f(x^\ast)=f(\hat{x})$.
On the other hand, if $\hat{x}$ is an alternative solution, then
\begin{equation*}
  f\big(x^\ast+\lambda(\hat{x}-x^\ast)\big)=f(x^\ast)=f(\hat{x}),
 \end{equation*}
so the function $h(\lambda):= f\big(x^\ast+\lambda(\hat{x}-x^\ast)\big)$ is constant on $[0,1]$, which yields $\left<\mathrm{grad} f(x^\ast),\hat{x}-x^\ast\right>=0$.
So far, everything is clear. It remains to prove that the first equality is also true. It is done by using the function $g(y):=f(y)-\left<y-x^\ast,\mathrm{grad} f(x^\ast)\right>$, which is also convex on $X$ and $g(x^\ast)=f(x^\ast)=f(\hat{x})=g(\hat{x})$. If $\mathrm{grad} f(\hat{x})\neq\mathrm{grad} f(x^\ast)$, then $\mathrm{grad} g(\hat{x})=\mathrm{grad} f(\hat{x})-\mathrm{grad} f(x^\ast)\neq0$, and so there is a vector $v$ such that $v^\top \mathrm{grad} g(\hat{x})<0$, in which case for a sufficiently small $\alpha>0$ we get $g(\hat{x}+\alpha t)<g(\hat{x})=g(x^\ast)$. This contradicts the minimum at $x^\ast$.
However, the last contradiction seems to be wrong, as we know nothing about the relation of $\hat{x}+\alpha t$ and the set $X$, i.e., the points $\hat{x}+\alpha t$ may not belong to $X$. I think that the statement is true only with the condition $\left<\mathrm{grad} f(\hat{x}),x^\ast-\hat{x}\right>=0$. Or am I wrong?
